# Referencing column heading text in form response spreadsheet in app script code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am writing an if function that basically says, "if this answer is ****, then pull the column heading text and replace a keyholder with that text."

I know how to reference a spot on the Spreadsheet form response (a specific cell) using e.values but what is the coding to refer to the column heading text itself?

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O63Em.png)

Comment: To clarify, you mean you want the value of the text in the first row of the sheet, for the column which was edited?

Comment: Could you share an example of the sheet and what the values would look with the condition?

Comment: @sinaraheneba that is correct :)

Comment: @Jescanellas just added a link to an image of the spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to immediately match question text to question answers, then use `e.namedValues` instead of `e.values`. [The documentation page describes the `namedValues` property as "An object containing the question names and values from the form submission."](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Example of getting the key from the value:

```js
function submitHandler(event) {
  for (var key in event.namedValues) {
    if (/magicValue/.test(event.namedValues[key])) {
      Logger.log("Found it: %s", key);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise if you have looked up the value you need in `e.values`, and the value is found in index `i`, then the column number will be the `i + 1`, and the header row will be `1`.  The text can be retrieved with [`Sheet.getRange(1, i + 1).getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))

e.g.

```js
var value = Sheet.getRange(1, i + 1).getValue()
```